# How can I make a transparent cursor, and why does my Photoshop document have grid-lines on it?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-format, background-removal

I am trying to make a cursor with transparency using Photoshop CS5. When I make a `.cur` file from an image, I can see extra white space with the icon

Something like this: [image]

I don't want the outer white space. I just want the guitar to be the cursor, but here the cursor is the full image.

Out of curiosity, I just dragged an default computers `.cur` file, and in PS it looks like this:

[image]

What grid is this? How can I enable this? Is this grid important to make `.cur` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid you are seeing is just the **Pixel Grid**. It is helpful when working with very small resolutions (such as icons/cursors). You can enable or disable it with **View** → **Show** → ***Pixel Grid***

[image: Pixel Grid]

To make a cursor with transparency, I would follow the tutorial [here](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3664822#3664822)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the guitar, use the Pen Tool in Photoshop and cut it out so only the guitar remains.